# jQuery fullcalendar to Persian

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to change jquery fullcalendar  to Persian calendar.

I am using this code:

```
   isRTL: true,
    monthNames: ['فروردين', 'ارديبهشت', 'خرداد', 'تير', 'مرداد', 'شهريور',
                'مهر', 'آبان', 'آذر', 'دي', 'بهمن', 'اسفند'],
    monthNamesShort: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
    dayNames: ['يکشنبه', 'دوشنبه', 'سه‌شنبه', 'چهارشنبه', 'پنجشنبه', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
    dayNamesShort: ['يکشنبه', 'دوشنبه', 'سه‌شنبه', 'چهارشنبه', 'پنجشنبه', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
    dayNamesMin: ['يکشنبه', 'دوشنبه', 'سه‌شنبه', 'چهارشنبه', 'پنجشنبه', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
    weekHeader: 'هفته',
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    firstDay: 6,
```

My UI has changed but may calendar is not Persian

Comment: Tentatively removing C#, ASP.NET, and SQL tags in favour of jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by "My UI changed but may calendar is not persian"

Comment: my ui means my Fullcalendar plugin in the web page.I want change to persian calender  www.arshaw.com/fullcalendar

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Answer (score 4):

[jalali-fullcalendar](https://github.com/faravaghi/jalali-fullcalendar) may help you. Even if you don't use PHP or Yii you can take a look and extract the methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascripts functions and classes the good sample for use this that has convert Gregorian to Persian or reverse  and render month in js follow this repository:

[mpdatepicker](https://github.com/4xmen/mpdatepicker)

for example functions:

```
getPersianWeekDay // return persian weekday
gDate2Timestamp // Gregorian to timestamp
pDate2Timestamp // persian to timestamp
pGetLastDayMonth // for find last persian month day
ShowMonth // show a persian months
Persian2Gregorian 
Gregorian2Persian
```